# Return to questions on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Using the Android app, I frequently select from the tags list to view recent questions on subjects I might be able to help with.

However, after viewing a question, tapping `back` (either the phone's default or the arrow in the top bar) returns me to the tags list, not the questions as one would expect. It makes for a frustrating user experience.

Any chance this could be altered in a forthcoming version?